# Golang WebDAV: how to correctly return dead properties for resource comment?

Tags: go, properties, webdav

Given is a struct type implementing the `webdav.File` and `webdav.DeadPropsHolder` interfaces.

```golang
type vdir struct {
    comment        string        // optional short comment for display.
    // ... other fields
}
```

How do I correctly return the dead property "comment" so that it is shown in Windows Explorer, and other WebDAV-enabled file managers? I tried this but without the comment showing up (comment is #PCDATA):

```golang
func (d *vdir) DeadProps() (map[xml.Name]webdav.Property, error) {
    return map[xml.Name]webdav.Property{
        {Space: "DAV:", Local: "comment"}: {
            XMLName:  xml.Name{Space: "DAV:", Local: "comment"},
            InnerXML: []byte(d.comment),
        },
    }, nil
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard "comment" property in WebDAV, so there's really no way to get standard clients to display this kind of additional information (unless they have a specific way to let them be configured for that).

Comment: I had found DAV:comment in RFC 3253, the versioning extensions to WebDAV and -- maybe wrongly -- assumed that they would be supported in common file managers. Is there some other supported means to attach a description or comment using some other WebDAV element?

Comment: Good point. I had forgotten about dav:comment in RFC 3253. Anyway, that would only help if clients would actually implement that; which is not the case in general. So I'm sorry, I don't believe there's anything you can use without getting the clients modifiied first.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies the situation. That's not the first time where we have standards with features that in the end people rarely use and thus support is missing.